# Swift 3 Getting Optionals After Initializing Class

Tags: swift

I have the following class called `User`

```
class User: CustomStringConvertible {
    var id: Int!
    var firstName: String!
    var lastName: String!

    init(){
    }

    init(id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }

    var description: String{
        return "id = \(id); first name = \(firstName); last name = \(lastName)"      
    }
}
```

I then call the class with the following code:

```
let user = User(id: userData["id"] as! Int, firstName: userData["first_name"] as! String, lastName: userData["last_name"] as! String)
```

After I call `print(user)` I get the following:

```
id = Optional(1); first name = Optional("John"); last name = Optional("Doe")
```

Why is it printing `Optional(1)`, `Optional("John")`, when my variables are defined by `Type!`. I know the answer is probably very simple however I can't figure it out. It was working fine in Swift 2.0

Comment: declare your class properties as constants and non optionals. `let id: Int
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String`

Comment: `id`, `firstName`, `lastName` should **not** be optionals. What `User` has no first name or last name?

Comment: I need init{} class there as well so I cannot simply delete the "!" else I will get an Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties error.

Comment: `class User: CustomStringConvertible {
    let id: Int
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    init(id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
    var description: String{
        return "id = \(id); first name = \(firstName); last name = \(lastName)"
    }
}`

Comment: @BhavikP. Then that's a logical error in your program. Creating a user with out that information doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 2, the type `Int!` was shorthand for `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Int>`. The compiler treated `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` specially: it could be treated like `Optional` in contexts that allowed an `Optional`, and automatically (implicitly) unwrapped in contexts that didn't allow an `Optional`.

The problem was that it was hard to understand what the compiler would do with an `Int!` in various circumstances. Here's one of many examples:

```
func f() -> Int! { return 3 }
let x1 = f()
```

What is the type of `x1` in that code, in Swift 2? Is it `Int`, `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Int>` (aka `Int!`), or `Optional<Int>` (aka `Int?`)? It turns out that in Swift 2, `x1` is type `Int?`. You'd have to be a language guru to know that.

You can find more examples in [this swift-evolution thread](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160314/012752.html) discussing the abolition of the `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` type.

For Swift 3, the Swift team adopted [SE-0054: Abolish `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` type](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md). SE-0054 removed the `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` type entirely and changed the meaning of `var id: Int!`. Now it declares that `id` has type `Optional<Int>`, but if you use `id` where **only** a plain `Int` is accepted, then the compiler implicitly unwraps it for you. **In all other contexts**, `id` is treated as a `Int?` (aka `Optional<Int>`). Whenever the compiler can treat `id` as `Int?`, it will do so.

This is why your results are different between Swift 2 and Swift 3. In Swift 2, the compiler would implicitly unwrap `id` (and the other properties) in more places than it will in Swift 3. Since string interpolation (`"\(...)"`) can accept *any* type, the Swift 3 compiler passes `id` as `Int?` instead of implicitly unwrapping it.

Answer (score 1):

Change the init constructor to something like this

```
init(id: Int!, firstName: String!, lastName: String!) {
        self.id = id
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
```

And the use `guard-if`statement to get a non-optional copy of the value

```
guard if let userID = userData["id"] as? Int, ..... else{
    return
}
```

Then initalize the `User` object with these values.